# verifying mount points on an Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

i am mounting multiple ebs volumes on an *ec2 instance* to perform some validations and check-sums but the problem is that before mounting volumes on the target mount point , i need to check whether that mount is not occupied, since i am creating mount points dynamically e.g

*test_lambda.py* *(e.g)*

```
device_prefixes = ['f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']
        attached_volumes = []
        
        
        try:
            for index,volume_id in enumerate(created_volumes):
                
                MOUNT_POINT = "/dev/sd{}".format(device_prefixes[index])
```

I have tried commands using **SSM** like **/proc/mounts, findmnt**, but they are displaying partitions and other volumes but not target like `(/dev/sde,/dev/sdf etc)`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html

Comment: can also share any article where i can programmatically  check the same  @jordanm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by jordan, i was able to clear my understanding about block device mapping , *boto3 ec2 client* has a method associated

```
`# where attribute can be one of the following`  `"""'|'kernel'|'ramdisk'|'userData'|'disableApiTermination'|'instanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior'|'rootDeviceName'|'blockDeviceMapping'|'productCodes'|'sourceDestCheck'|'groupSet'|'ebsOptimized'|'sriovNetSupport'|'enaSupport'|'enclaveOptions'|'disableApiStop',z"""`
        print(instance.describe_attribute(
    instance.describe_attribute(
                Attribute='blockDeviceMapping',
                DryRun=False,
                
                )
```

it does give us info about certain resources, apologies if my question was not clear in the first place,

> {'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs':
> {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 12, 4, 1,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-05bb41df0e6bc4bf3'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdl',
> 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 15, 51,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': False, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-00be0e0f001fea1a9'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdm',
> 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 15, 51,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': False, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-09c552e77ba2a563f'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdn',
> 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 15, 52,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': False, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-08d28a4ffe5e71dff'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdo',
> 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 15, 53,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': False, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-0e63fa17bd6185ee3'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdf',
> 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 36, 42,
> tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': False, 'Status': 'attached',
> 'VolumeId': 'vol-058de095fcfb1ef05'}}, {'DeviceName': '/dev/sdg',
> 'Ebs': {'Atta

Comment: You may also find the `nvme list` command from that document helpful for your goal.